# Get Data from External Apllication ( no server )

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

in a flash projector i need to retrieve data from an application on the same computer.
i know that i can call this application with fscommand. but is there a way to get the response back? for example if i would call a unix binary like "uptime" i would like to load the response "11:14  up 1 day, 16:14, 2 users, load averages: 0,47 0,73 0,88" back into flash.
is this possible at all?

so far i only worked with custom made local servers running as a deamon in the background. however for this project this would be too expensive...

any other ideas?

thanks a lot!

Comment: are you targeting air or flash ?

Comment: This is possible with AIR but not with Flash Player (or projector).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with AIR 2.0 (and above) by packaging your application as a native install application and using the NativeProcess class.

This [Adobe quickstart tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html) should get you started.

There's also a [sample application](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/samples_actionscript.html) (Mac only) which uses this technique to communicate with a native feature of OS X. It's called SearchCentral and it's about half-way down the page.

If you're completely wedded to the idea of running your app as a projector for whatever reason, you can, as Todd points out below, use Zinc and its [System.execStdOut()](http://www.multidmedia.com/support/livedocs/4.0/index.php?url=main.php?action=methods%C2%ACclass=System%C2%ACid=10149) method.

Comment: I agree AIR would be my first choice, another option if you are willing to spend some money is to use Zinc's `System.execStdOut()`

Comment: Do you want to add that as an answer Todd or are you happy for me to pad out mine with it?

Comment: Keep it on yours as I think your solution is better for most people, and you could use more rep :)

Comment: Haha, I sure could use more rep Todd. Thanks, you're a gent.